# Can anyone please tell me which error it is . linker error or compiler error

Tags: c, linker-errors, extern

Can anyone please explain me why it is linker error ?

Assuming that the variable `i` is not defined in any other file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    i=10;
    printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why *what* is an error? What does the error message say?

Comment: i is not defined but just declared. You must define it as a global or local variable without extern.

Comment: @Gerhardh The request specifies that "i" is not defined elsewhere

Comment: @RachidK. Sorry. Clearly an out of coffee error situation. ;)

Comment: It is a linker error. You promised the compiler (with `extern`) that the linker would find it, but it did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because you have said (extern) that the variable is defined somewhere else, but you have not linked with anything that contains a definition of the variable.

Example:

```
$ cat > main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    i=10;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}

$ cat > extern.c
int i;

$ gcc -c main.c 
$ gcc -c extern.c
$ ls
extern.c  extern.o  main.c  main.o
```

So now we have compiled the source files to object files. Let's link:

```
$ gcc main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `i'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `i'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ooops, did not work. But this does:

```
$ gcc main.o extern.o
$ ls
a.out  extern.c  extern.o  main.c  main.o
$ ./a.out 
10
$
```

> Assuming that the variable i is not defined in any other file.

It's a very strange assumption, because `extern` basically means that it is defined in another file. You're both assuming that it is defined in another file and that it's not. It's about the same thing as asking why you get an error when you try to open a file that does not exist. If you make assumptions that contradict each other, you should expect some kind of trouble, because no trouble would indeed be weird. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare your variable `i` as `extern` but you don't link it with anything that have the definition of the variable `i`.

Further reading on : [Extern C++](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/28730/extern)

Comment: Linking to a C++ explanation in a C question is dubious.